# The meaning of either in following sentence

Tags: meaning, word-usage

The Queen was enjoying being queen and what better way to remain so than to merry the prince herself.  The prince however did not like the idea either

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Ehsan. It would be helpful if you could provide with a link to the source of this text, so that we can work out what it might mean in context.

Comment: Merry the prince. Did you mean 'marry'?.

Comment: Yes I meant marry and my problem is exactly this the sentence sounds wrong but  I was watching a film in which the narrator said this sentence

Comment: Without the audio or the script, we cannot tell if you misheard or if the narrator simply does not speak English well.

Comment: What was the film?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean 'marry the prince'. The use of 'either' in the second sentence is wrong, and the sentence does not mean anything. This is because 'either' after a statement is used, with a negative statement (e.g. 'didn't') to link with a negative statement just made. You say that the prince 'did not like the idea either', but you have not previously said that a first person did not like the idea.

The man did not like cold baths. His son did not either. (His son, also, did not like cold baths).

[Either](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/either)

Comment: Yes I meant marry and my problem is exactly this the sentence sounds wrong but I was watching a film in which the narrator said this sentence

Comment: The sentence sounds wrong because it **is** wrong.

Comment: It could be right if, in a preceding sentence, we had heard about some other idea that the prince didn't like, and *the* were replaced with *that*. <description of idea>. The prince didn't like that idea. <description of another idea>. The prince didn't like that idea either.